# DirectX and C# and Windows RT

Tags: c#, windows-8, directx

I am building an app that using Bing Maps API with C#.

It require me to include MS Visual C++ Runtime Package so it can pass the WACK test.

Due to Bing Maps API, I can't compile the app with "Any CPU setting", it need to be manually to build the package for each ARM, x64 and x86. When trying to submit to the Windows Store, and it fail the certification of "requirement 3.8" and "requirement 3.9".

The fail reasons mainly are related to ARM package, and I don't know how to resolve it with C# coding? Or I Must code it with C++ ?

Answer (score 0):

Note the steps in [Add Bing Maps to a Windows Store app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855146.aspx)

> Add a reference to Bing Maps SDK for C#, C++, or Visual Basic.
>
> Set the Active solution platform in Visual Studio to one of the
>   following options.
>
> ```
>  C#, Visual Basic: ARM, x86 or x64
>  C++: ARM, Win32 or x64
> ```
>
> If you are using C# or Visual basic, you must add a reference to
>   Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package